# Read user input while text is constantly printing to console (Without curses?)

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to print text to the console while at the same time, reading user input. But every time I do that while typing the user input usually gets cut in half by output. I would rather not use curses as an option because that just seems overkill for what I'm trying to do, as I would only be using it to grab user input.

```
[Log] This is a log 
input

[Log] This inpis a log 
ut
```

I've also seen a Windows only solution, but that doesn't help me much. Are there any libraries to do this in a multiplatform way?

Comment: What a shame that there is no real answer still :/

Answer (score -1):

To do this using Java, you are going to need to use **Threading**.

Java Threading [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Oracle concurrency [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Check out this [**similar answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301892/print-to-console-while-waiting-for-input-in-java), I think it will put you in the right direction:

**Basically**, you will have your main program running, and a Thread running. They will run simultaneously. I think it'd be simplest to have the Thread do the printing, and your main program do the input.

One caveat: If you want your program to be able to print different things (not just repeat the same println()), you may need to stop the previous Thread and kick off another when you want it to say different things.

I hope that helps!

Comment: That still does the input getting cut off mid typing that I was talking about.

Comment: You're looking for a way to prevent the user from typing at the same time as output? You could use a GUI like [JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), rather than the console, and have output go to one spot, and input in another so there is no possible overlap.

Comment: GUI isn't really an option for what I'm doing.

Comment: How about the other part of my answer? Print to one place, and they put input in another place. Otherwise, you're out of luck without curses.